# Check day is the last working day of the month

Tags: excel

I need to write the formula to check the last working day of the month in excel.

Data look like this:

`|   Date   |
| 2018/10/22 |
| 2018/10/31 |`

The output should be:

`|   Date    | Check  |
| 2018/10/22 |   o    | 
| 2018/10/31 |   x    |`

Working day: from Mon to Friday, No holidays.

Comment: More detail probably needed. Do you mean just the last day of the month? Because the last *working* day may depend on what's actually considered to be weekend, whatever public holidays are in force in your locality, and a plethora of other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. further detail added.

Answer (score 1):

The 'last working day of the month' is a bit ambiguous given different holiday structures and the fact that not everyone works Monday to Friday. However, if a list of local holidays is provided in Z2:Z13, the [WORKDAY.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d) function should be able to return the last workday of any month with a variety of work and holiday schedules.

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(EOMONTH(A2, 0)+1, -1, "0000011", Z$2:Z$13)
```

For the purpose of demonstration, I've added the weekday to the date format with a custom number format of `ddd, yyyy/mm/dd_)`.

In the following sample image, note that the fictional holiday of Wed, 2018/01/31 pushed the 'last workday of the month' to Tue, 2018/01/30 and March's last day is Fri, 2018/03/30 since Saturday is considered a non-workday.

[image]