# Filter Data Using AutoFilter Criteria for all records in column from yesterday workday

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code filtering column by date, showing only yesterday's records.
How can I modify that code to show  workdays, so if I run it on Monday it would show Fridays records? Is it possible?

```
Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$F$50").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=2, _
        Operator:=11, Criteria2:=0, SubField:=0
```

Comment: I don't really see how this is a problem given the functionality of WORKDAY.INTL. See [Check day is the last working day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028567/check-day-is-the-last-working-day-of-the-month/53028652#53028652).

Comment: btw, and i'm just curious, but what version of excel do you have that supports `SubField:=0`and xlOr isn't 2 and xlAnd isn't 1. In fact, I'm very curious as to what `Operator:=11` represents.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my Regional settings:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim datestring As String, d As Date, sr As String

    d = Now()
    d = d - 1
    sr = Format(d, "dddd")
    If sr = "Saturday" Then d = d - 1
    If sr = "Sunday" Then d = d - 2
    datestring = "=" & Format(d, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$F$50").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        datestring, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]